# Determining the Jordan canonical form from minimal and characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

For $A\in\mathbb{C}^{5\times 5}$ it is known that $p_A(\lambda)=(\lambda-2)^3(\lambda+7)^2$ and $m_A(\lambda)=(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda+7)$. Here, $p_A$ is the characteristic and $m_A$ is the minimal polynomial. Then what is the Jordan canonical form of $A$?

The only thing I could think of was to use $m_A(\Lambda +N)=0$ where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $N$ is the direct sum of tight shifts. However this is a bit messy, and I am sure there is a fast way, so how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

The Matrix you are looking for is the following
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1&0&0&0\\
0&2&0&0&0\\
0&0&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&-7&0\\
0&0&0&0&-7
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Infact the powers of the minimal polynomial gives you the necessary informations about the Jordan blocks. Since the power of the first factor is $2$, and the eigenvalue has algebraic multiplicity $3$ the only possibility is that the Jordan block has the following form:

$$ J_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&2
\end{pmatrix},
$$

because the nilpotent part of $J_2$ has nilpotent order $2$.

Moreover the second factor has power $1$, so there is no nilpotent part, and the Jordan block is:

$$J_{-7}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-7&0\\
0&-7
\end{pmatrix}, 
$$

infact the nilpotent part has nilpotent order $1$, so it is necessarily the zero matrix.

Comment: And why can't it be $$ J_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&2
\end{pmatrix},
$$? I'm really sorry, this might be completely clear, but i didn't understand that much in the lecture :)

Comment: Maybe you mean the matrix$ $ J_2= \begin{pmatrix} 2&0&0\\ 0&2&1\\ 0&0&2 \end{pmatrix}$$..in this case the difference in given by the order of elements generating  the eigenspace $V_2$.

Comment: @user109899 The JCF is unique up to reordering of the Jordan blocks.